# Intellij Idea не удается собрать (развернуть?) приложение

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, развертывание

Прописал артефакт "JavaFX приложение", выбило такую ошибку:

[image: Ошибка]

Погуглил, там ребята советовали перенести папку .IntelliJ Idea в другое место, где не будет русских букв в пути. И прописать этот путь в bin/idea.properties в system.path. Перезапустил, она спросила, где находится папка с найтройками (я же её перенес), я указал, но оно всё равно упрямо создало папку в домашней директории и лезет туда.

Answer (score 1):

В общем проблема действительно была в русских буквах в пути (мда.. грустненько с этим сталкиваться при работе с java да ещё и в 2016 году). В том файле нужно было отредактировать не только system.path, но и config.path. И не забыть проверить чтобы бы они были раскомментированы.